# Proper design of member setters/getters in a C++ class

Tags: c++

The usual way of designing setters and getters for a class member is the following

```
class QNumber 
{
    public:
        void setNumber(unsigned int xNumber){ this->mValue = xNumber; };
        unsigned int getNumber(void) const { return this->mValue; };

    private:
        unsigned int mValue;
}
```

If the member is another class (e.g. `QRational` as opposed to `unsigned int`), then the getter would be better returning a reference, in terms of performance.

So the modified design would be

```
class QNumber 
{
    public:
        const QRational & value(void) const  { return  mValue;} // getter
              QRational & value(void)        { return  mValue;} // 'setter'

    private:
        QRational mValue;
}
```

My question is - isn't there something potentially wrong with the latter approach? I have not seen it much in other people's code and to me, it seems more elegant than set/get method.

Many thanks, 
Daniel

Comment: The performance bit is not true until you benchmark it. The `const& QRational` version forces you to always store a valid `QRational` in your implementation, as opposed for example to generating it on the fly, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Your point about pessimization is just as debatable as the OP point about optimization. Premature optimization is very evil, though.

Comment: in the latter design QNumber object is not aware of every possible mValue change...

Comment: 2 things bother me withe your latter code. First, as stated above, your "setter" might break encapsulation. Second, it could backfire as it makes it easy to call setter instead of getter and vice versa.

Comment: The proper design for setters and (to a lesser extent) getters is to avoid them as much as possible...

Answer (score 3):

The point of getters and setters is to separate the interface from the implementation. If you return a reference, it has to point somewhere in the implementation. Now if you change the implementation, you'll have to start returning by value instead.

Personally I prefer `public` nonstatic members when the need for anything else is unlikely. Reference-semantic getters and setters provide the worst of both worlds. (I am working on a [proposal](http://bit.ly/genlife) to improve them, though.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Potatoswatter's answer, please note one more point.

You second design provokes usage in the following form:

```
QRational& r = number.value(); 
// or
const QRational& r = number.value();
```

thus the user retains the *reference* to your inner object. It will be somewhat more difficult to manage in case your `number` object can be destroyed or moved while `r` is still there. This does not even depend on whether the `const` or non-`const` method is used.

The first design does not expose such problems.

Comment: My answer was going to include this but I decided the example was contrived. See the linked ISO proposal draft, though, it's all about eliminating dangling references through static analysis.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my opinion, if that member acts like an unsigned int (e.g., allows assignment to/from an unsigned int), and you're really sure this class should support direct manipulation of that member (i.e., it should have a "getter" and "setter" at all), then you should at least make access to it clean, rather than requiring other code to be written around that implementation detail. To avoid that, you should define how the type of this object differs from a plain unsigned int, then implement that behavior in a class that defines that type properly and directly.

```
class QNumber { // bad name--looks like a Qt class name
    unsigned int value;
public:
    QNumber(unsigned int value = 0) : value(value) {}
    QNumber &operator=(unsigned int val) { value = val; return *this; }
    operator unsigned int() { return value; }
};
```

With this, client code can be readable--instead of ugliness like `x.SetNumber(2);` or `x.SetNumber() = 2;` you just use `x = 2;`. This also avoids all sorts of lifetime issues that arise when you let a client get a pointer or reference to the class' internals (which you should generally avoid).